# Failure of training a face landmark detection model with Dlib and iBug

Tags: c++, face-detection, feature-detection, training-data, dlib

I've kept trying to create a better model than `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` which Dlib provides.

(You can get this file from: http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2)

---

#### Question

Do you have any ideas why my dataset is not trained in a right way?

[My result with applying all iBug images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgxIB.jpg)

---

#### Goal

I want to create a `.dat` file which provides better accuracy than the model I mentioned above.
It means better accuracy than this image.

---

#### What I used.

I basically used an example code of `train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp`.

And dataset I used is this -> 
Original: http://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/resources/300-W/
What I actually used: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/11znddaomgjfdw1/AAC9up5NOGTv2mc0dpYH6z4-a?dl=0 + iBug Data in `Image` directory.

My Directory was like this:

`* name: /faces_iBug
* Image
  * I put all of the iBug images in this directory.
* 2008_002470.jpg
* 2008_002506.jpg
* 2008_004176.jpg
* 2008_007676.jpg
* 2009_004587.jpg
* image_metadata_stylesheet.xsl
* testing_with_face_landmarks.xml
* training_with_face_landmarks.xml`

Then, I tried like,

`$ ./train_shape_predictor_ex ~/faces_iBug`

---

#### What I tried.

1. **Put object bounding box with `imglab`.**

   - Since the raw data installed from iBug doesn't have bounding box information, I put those information by using `imglab` which is a tool provided in Dlib.
   - I only wrote the bounding box and combined with annotation data to create the train data.
   - The data I created is in the directory I put on my Dropbox. The file name is `training_with_face_landmarks.xml`.
2. Changing Parameters

   - Firstly, I thought the failure is just because the parameters didn't fit to create the model.
   - Even I tried couple of parameter combinations, the problem didn't look like to be solved.
3. Applied same dataset for both train and test data (with only 11 images).

   - This suceeded to create a right model. But I'm not sure why.
   - I actually used smaller dataset of only 11 images.
   - Though the acuracy is pretty bad, still it seems like the trainer could learn train data in a right way.
   - The result was like this.
4. Applied same dataset for both train and test data (with all of the iBug images).

   - Then I thought just applying same dataset for both train and test data might be the technique to create a model with Dlib.
   - But, it didn't actually work for this try as always.
   - The result was like this.
     [The result with applying all iBug images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgxIB.jpg)

---

- My Environment
- OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.6)
- The C compiler identification: AppleClang 7.3.0.7030029
- Dlib: dlib-19.1

Comment: are you trying to create model with less than 68 points?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to make 'better' model of the one the author of Dlib provided.